# onCreate() called with onBackPressed but not by pressing the back button

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Okay I'm sort of confused. I have two activities: Activity A and Activty B, I can navigate to B from A very easily. Once at B when I press the physical back button, Activity B dies and I'm right back where I left off at A. However, if instead I call onBackPressed(), Activity B dies but Activity A is created from scratch (onCreate() called).

I can understand that I can not rely on Activity A being kept alive etc. but pressing the back button works every time whereas onBackPressed() fails every time. I was under the assumption that onBackPressed and pressing the button did the same thing.

Appreciate all help!

Launching Activity B:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MailActivity.class);
    Mail m = mMails.get(position);
    i.putExtra(MailFragment.EXTRA_MAIL, m);
    Log.d(TAG, "Mail Packed");
    startActivity(i);
```

Trying to back to A from B:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return false;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be calling onBackPressed() explicitly, I'm pretty sure that is not encouraged behavior. You should likely not being doing that. Is there any particular reason why you are calling that API? What other alternatives do you have.

Comment: @JoxTraex Well I tried to pass flagged intents but was unable to mimic the hardware back button functionality. Pressing back works fine, pressing the home button then going back to the app works fine (all as expected) but the back buttons starts the Activity afresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the Intent flags you are sending when you do `context.startActivity(intent);`

You can set intent flags

```
intent.setFlags(FLAGS_GO_HERE | ANOTHER_FLAG_IF_YOU_WANTED);
```

More details: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Changed the launchMode to singleTop, works perfectly now. I figured the launch mode was not the problem since the hardware button was functioning correctly but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I didn't return `true` in `onOptionsItemSelected`. This resulted in the parent activity's `onCreate()` being called.

Once I added `return true` in `onOptionsItemSelected`, I could see the expected behaviour.

Comment: This was my problem as well, and seems like a more logical explanation for the deviation from expected behavior. If you `return false` or `return super.onOptionsItemSelected()`, you're allowing the app to do extra work that's out of your control, which in this case results in the Activity being destroyed (for whatever reason). Simply `return true` and the event will stop there.